# How can I stop SetInterval on route change which is called via service in component in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have made one service for all my socket methods.

socket.service.ts

*

```
//get buy orders
    public getBuyOrder = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.socket.emit('buy_orders', { 'crypto': this.pair_to, 'currency': this.pair_from });
        }, 1000);
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            this.socket.on('buy_orders', (message) => {
                observer.next(message);
            });
        });
    }
```

*

and i am calling that service in my component,

order-buy.component.ts

```
getBuyData() {
        this.buy_socket=this.socketservice.getBuyOrder().subscribe(
            data => {
                // console.log(data);
                this.temp = data;
                if (this.temp.status == 200) {

                    this.no_data_found = false;

                    this.buy_data = this.temp.data;
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.buy_data.length; i++) {
                        this.previous = 0;
                        for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                            this.previous += this.buy_data[j].quantity;
                        }
                        this.quantity.push(this.previous.toFixed(2));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.no_data_found = true;
                    this.no_data=this.temp.message;
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Will clear when component is destroyed e.g. route is navigated away from.
        clearInterval(this.buy_socket);
        console.log("order-buy ngDestroy called!");
    }
```

but on ngOnDestroy() my timeInterval doesn't stop and continues to execute oven on route change.

Can anyone suggest me the better way of closing timeInterval if i am calling method from service?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe your call in component destroy method.

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
        this.buy_socket.unsubscribe();
        console.log("order-buy ngDestroy called!");
    }
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted and give upvote if you think its worth.. Thanks in advance

Comment: @DharaPatel click on tick mark to show that you accepted my answer which is below the upvote